# How to trigger div like <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

There is a div box on the web site and there is a link. I want to click to container in order to trigger `<a>`:

```
<a href="#">sapien sed</a>
```

but When I clicked on the container div, it does not give response or it is in the infinite loop.
How can I solve this problem?
That is to say; I want to click the div to trigger `<a>`

The whole code:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse congue molestie venenatis.
        In adipiscing vulputate sem. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum nisl nibh, interdum sit amet pulvinar at,
        malesuada vitae lacus. Aliquam semper <a href="#">sapien sed</a> risus laoreet ultrices. Donec volutpat felis eu justo
        bibendum tempus. Donec non purus sed sapien fringilla tempor ut et metus. Nulla ipsum nibh, dapibus
        ac ornare vitae, fermentum nec nulla.
    </p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("div.container").each(function(){
            var $container = $(this);
            $container.find("a:first").each(function(){
                var $link = $(this);
                $container
                    .css("cursor", "pointer")
                    .click(function(e){
                        $link.trigger("click");
                        return false;
                    });
                $link.bind("click", function(e){
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    return true;
                });
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: It seems to work to me: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/5bfN9/

Comment: Can't really understand what you're trying to do here. Can you explain what u actually want to happen?

Comment: When I clicked to link, it works but I want to click the div to trigger. but it does not work

Comment: @csharpexe - See the link I posted. Clicking anywhere in the `div` triggers the click event bound to the `a` element.

Comment: Then your are doing something else wrong. Have a look at @James's fiddle, it works.

Comment: Please write <a href="http://www.google.com">, when I clicked to "sapien sed" it triggers, but div does not..

Comment: This could be because your code has a bug in preceding lines before the event is bound and therefore the event listener is never registered.

Comment: @csharpexe - It triggers the *event handler* bound to the element. It will not trigger the default behaviour of the link. You could use `window.location` inside the event handler to simulate the link being physically clicked.

Comment: @lthibodeaux  I will try again with clarified page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're expecting `trigger("click")` to cause the default behaviour of the link to occur (i.e. you are expecting the link to be followed and the page it links to loaded). However, that is not what [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) does. All it does is execute the `click` event handler function bound to the element.

To actually follow the link, you could grab the `href` and use `window.location`:

```
$link.bind("click", function(e){
   window.location = $link.attr("href");
   e.stopPropagation();
   return true;
});
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/5bfN9/3/).

Comment: I solved problem with below solution:



     $this.bind("click", function(e){
                        var href = $(this).attr("href") || null;
                        if ( href ) {
                            window.location = $(this).attr("href");
                        }
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        return true;
                    });

Sometimes there can be onclick but not href so I do this.

Answer (score 1):

To trigger standart "href" links and links with onClick event at the same time:

```
$(function() { 
    $("div.container").each(function(){
        var $container = $(this);
        $container.find("a:first").each(function(){
            var $this = $(this),
                onClick = this.onclick || null;
            $container
                .css("cursor", "pointer")
                .click(function(e){
                    $link.trigger("click");
                    return false;
                });
            $link.bind("click", function(e){
                if ( !onClick ) {
                    window.location = $(this).attr("href");
                }
                e.stopPropagation();
                return true;
            });
        });
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.container').css("cursor", "pointer").click(function(){
        window.location = $('a', this).first().attr('href');
    });
});
```

Comment: This is the same as trigger, see James Allardice's answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("div.container").click(function()
{
  $('a:first', $(this)).click();
});
```

Comment: Should not use `:first` unless necessary.

Comment: This is the same as trigger, see James Allardice's answer.

Answer (score -1):

to make sure, add the function inside of the

```
$(document).ready(function() { });
```

otherwise the div might not load before the code runs.

Comment: The code is already inside of `$(function(){...}` which is the same as `$(document).ready`.